# Html.Editor() helper in ASP.NET MVC 3 does not work as expected with array in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics, dynamic, collections

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application I have classes like the following:

```
public class Localization<T>
{
    public int VersionID { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Localizable<T>
{
    public Localization<T>[] Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then, I have the following view:

```
@model dynamic
...
@for (int i = 0; i < VersionCount; i++)
{
    ...
    @Html.Editor(string.Format("Name[{0}].Value", i))
    ...
}
```

Now, when I display this view, passing a subclass of `Localizable<string>` as the model, the textboxes for the strings are rendered, but they are empty. If I replace `@Html.Editor(string.Format("Name[{0}].Value", i))` with `@InputExtensions.TextBox(Html, string.Format("Name[{0}].Value", i), Model.Name[i].Value)`, the textboxes are correctly filled with values from the model. However, using TextBox instead of Editor is not an option for me, because I want to use different editor templates for different types of T. So, what am I doing wrong, or is it a bug in MVC, and is there any workaround?

Comment: I'm thinking its just a typo, but when you do the .Editor you forgot a ']'

Comment: What happens when you do `Html.Editor(Name[i])`

Comment: @bobek An error: "The name 'Name' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @bobek Error: "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'Editor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute UIHint("MyUIHintName").

```
public class Localizable<T>
{
    [UIHint("MyUIHintName")]
    public Localization<T>[] Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you need to create folder Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/. Next you need create Razor View
Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyUIHintName.cshtml
In this view you can write logic for every type, for example:

```
@model dynamic

@if(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType.Name=="string")
{
    //Do something
}
@if(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType.Name=="int")
{
    //Do something
}
```